# JSTERROR: canceling statement due to user request

Tags: database, postgresql, jdbc

What could be the cause for following error?

```
2016-11-16 00:30:10.022 JSTERROR: canceling statement due to user request
2016-11-16 00:30:10.022 JSTCONTEXT: SQL statement "update login_history set remarks = current_timestamp where picked_status = 'NOTPICKED'"
PL/pgSQL function get_charge_history(character varying) line 17 at SQL statement
2016-11-16 00:30:10.022 JSTSTATEMENT: select parentcust,chargetrxid,updateddate,commandtxid,mvn oid,customerid,extraplanid,baseplanid,oldbaseplan_ id,asvolume,asprice,chargetype,updatedremarks from get_charge_history($1)

2016-11-16 00:40:10.018 JSTERROR: canceling statement due to user request
2016-11-16 00:40:10.018 JSTCONTEXT: SQL statement "update loginn_history set remarks = current_timestamp where picked_status = 'NOTPICKED'"
PL/pgSQL function get_charge_history(character varying) line 17 at SQL statement
2016-11-16 00:40:10.018 JSTSTATEMENT: select parentcust,chargetrxid,updateddate,commandtxid,mvn oid,customerid,extraplanid,baseplanid,oldbaseplan_ id,asvolume,asprice,chargetype,updatedremarks from get_charge_history($1)
```

Is the above happening due to select and update operation happening at same time? And what could be the solution for this?

Comment: It means user aborted execution. by e.g "Ctrl+C"

Comment: Are you using both MySQL and PostgreSQL? If not, please just tag with the one you are using.